# iOS - Moving view does not animate

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have toolbar on my view and I want to move it with animation, but the animation does not work, the toolbar move quickly to the new position. I use it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.toolbarBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = editing ? 0 : -44;
}];
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried just changing animation block sentences and it worked for me:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    self.bottomMargin.constant = editing ? 0 : -44; 
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
}];
```

Comment: You are right, it work, probably layoutIfNeeded should be last.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki Im trying to give my answer, an objective-c format but I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean objective-c format? I just add some space at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Did you add your code between pre tags? When you edit your answer in the toolbar should be Code Sample.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
    animations:^{
        yourView.center = CGPointMake(yourView.frame.size.width/2, -44);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Comment: Because he is using autolayout. You can't really directly manipulate frame (center, origin...) when using this feature.